# Hyperspheres inside of a Hypercube

Tags: differential-geometry

How many $4$-dimensional hyperspheres with a diameter of $1$ can fit inside a $4$-dimensional hypercube of length of $2$?

Answer (score 1):

There's just enough room to squeeze another unit 4D hypersphere inside the obvious pack of 16 others.